# show address from latitude and long latitude

Tags: php, latitude-longitude

I have query to show latlong like this:

```
Latitude : <?=$post_search['lat'];?>
Long Latitude : <?=$post_search['long'];?>
```

sample result:

```
Latitude : -7.966620399999998
Long Latitude : 112.63263210000002
```

How can I create a function to show the address based the query:

```
<?=$post_search['lat'];?>
<?=$post_search['long'];?>
```

my code use this library: [see in pastebin](https://pastebin.com/VseMAbEn)

Comment: do you mean that you need a function to convert lat long values to actual address string? if so, you can take a look at [google maps reverse geocoding api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your library. But it make simply without any libraries.
You should use googleapis geocode.

it's simple query

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=44.4647452,7.3553838&sensor=true
```

you have need set `lat` `lng` in your request and run this, after request you parse json.

example for php:

```
const GOOGLE_MAPS_URL = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json';

function getUrlLatLng( $latLng) {
   $queryString =  http_build_query(['latlng' => $latLng,'sensor'=> true]);
   return GOOGLE_MAPS_URL . '?' .  $queryString;
}

function getData($lat, $lng) {
    $latLng = implode(',',[$lat, $lng]);
    $url = getUrlLatLng($latLng);
    return json_decode(file_get_contents($url)); 
}

function parseAddress($result) {

    return ($result[0]->formatted_address); //this parse address ass field you need;
}

function getAddress($lat, $lng) {
   $address = (array)@getData($lat, $lng);

   if(empty((array)@$address['results'])) {
     throw new Exception('Not result'); 
   }

   return $address['results'];
}

function getFullAddress($lat, $lng) {
   $address = getAddress($lat, $lng);
   return parseAddress($address);
}

$result = getFullAddress(-7.966620399999998, 112.63263210000002);

echo $result;
```